# 404 error in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I am hitting http://127.0.0.1:8000/segment_address but I am getting 404 error:

This is my urls.py

```
from addFixAPI import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'segment_address', views.search_addresses,base_name='segment_address')

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
                   url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
                   url(r'^locality/', include('locality.urls')),
                   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                   url(r'^django-rq/', include('django_rq.urls')),
)
```

Comment: Are the other urls are working?

Comment: Does [`http://127.0.0.1:8000/segment_address/`](http://127.0.0.1:8000/segment_address/) with a slash at the end work?

Comment: @onyeka Yes other urls are working
Added slash as well. Still not resolved.

Answer (score 2):

First you should check that "app" has registered its "urls" in the main "urls" project.

It is obvious but I dont see that you include the line

`from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers`

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you register long URLs first. ie: segment_address/things/*pk*/ must be registered before segment_address/
2. You have to register your ViewSet class. I see a snake_case name in your register(), which implies you are either not following PEP 8, or you are not registering a class that extends a viewset.
   See here for examples:
   https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

And just in case anyone finds it useful: You don't use .as_view() when registering in the router. You only need .as_view() if you are registering using the url() method.